# Dataset for human body temperature, heart rate and illness

Tags: data-request, medical

For testing my healthcare project I'm looking for a data set in which the following attributes are present:

```
gender temperature heart-rate   illness
  1        100         70       high temperature (fever)
  2        101         94       high temperature with high rate
```

Comment: Medical data tends to not be open to protect the patient's privacy. That being said, maybe have a look at this (and the links in the description): https://github.com/openmhealth/sample-data-generator

Comment: Related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9808/open-large-datasets-on-human-body-temperature

Answer (score 0):

Hey recently i just got these dataset :

### [Open large datasets on human body temperature?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9808/open-large-datasets-on-human-body-temperature)

https://www2.stetson.edu › ...XLS
Web results
Normal Temperature data

Comment: Link is to another Opendata question about temperature only. That does not answer the question here.